# An alternate EJB query for DISTINCT

Tags: jpa, ejb

For some reason I am having trouble witha  software package that won't properly return queries such as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.name FROM EMPS p, IN (p.customerBean) c WHERE c.cost = '500'
```

or variations with navigation like:

```
SELECT p.customerBean.name FROM EMPS p WHERE p.customerBean.cost = '500'
```

However this will work:

```
SELECT p FROM EMPS p, IN (p.customerBean) c WHERE c.cost = '500'.
```

Well, is there a way I can manipulate the last query to return somethings like the first two strictly using the first half of:

```
SELECT p FROM EMPS p, ...
```

Can I use DISTINCT later on in the statement, AND or a GROUP BY, and if so, how?

Answer (score -1):

SELECT DISTINCT c.name FROM EMPS p join p.customerBean c WHERE c.cost = '500'